# Identifying targetList in ember-drag-sort

Tags: ember.js, drag-and-drop, ember-drag-sort

I am currently trying to implement an [ember-drag-sort](https://github.com/Deveo/ember-drag-sort) nested list into my Ember.js app.

Is there a way to determine in the dragEnd action which "sub-list" the item has been dropped into? (e.g. a class name, id etc)

In my scenario, I am sorting ember data records that can belong to each other (i.e. a nested, 'tree' structure). When I drag one nested record "into" another (making the dragged record a child of the second record), I need to update the parent attribute in ember-data. My question is, how do you pass some id of the second record (the new parent) to the dragEnd action?

Is this even possible?

---

EDIT:

To put it another way, I want to be able to identify which list I have dropped the item into.

Comment: Do you want to move the parent of the dragged record to the target list alongside the original record?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My apologies, I have clarified my original post.

Answer (score 1):

`targetList` refers to the array on the dragged side of the component. For pushing the parent to the target list alongside the child, you can take a look at this [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/#/e4e928934018dcd2ed3049c36e8414b3).

Answer (score 0):

To simplify identification of lists, the [additional arguments](https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-drag-sort/#passing-additional-arguments) feature has been implemented by @rwwagner90 ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1732456/rwwagner90), [GitHub](https://github.com/rwwagner90)).

You can pass some kind of list identifier into the `additionalArgs` argument to your lists. In this example I'm passing `parent` records which own the lists:

```
{{#each parents as |parent|}}
  {{#drag-sort-list
    items          = parent.children
    additionalArgs = (hash parent=parent)
    dragEndAction  = (action 'dragEnd')
    as |child|
  }}
    {{child.name}}
  {{/drag-sort-list}}
{{/each}}
```

In the `dragEnd` action you can access the parent records that own the source list and the target list:

```js
dragEndAction({ sourceList, sourceIndex, sourceArgs, targetList, targetIndex, targetArgs }) {
  if (sourceModel === targetModel && sourceIndex === targetIndex) return;

  const item = sourceList.objectAt(sourceIndex);
  sourceList.removeAt(sourceIndex);
  targetList.insertAt(targetIndex, item);

  // Access the parent via `sourceArgs` and `targetArgs`
  sourceArgs.parent.save();
  targetArgs.parent.save();
}
```